# How to find three parameters that will optimally make a curve fit into another curve in python?

Tags: python, interpolation, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have two datasets (t1,y1) and (t2,y2) which when plotted would give their respective curves.

Below is my data:

```
t1 = [-2.        , -1.6877551 , -1.3755102 , -1.06326531, -0.75102041,
       -0.43877551, -0.12653061,  0.18571429,  0.49795918,  0.81020408,
        1.12244898,  1.43469388,  1.74693878,  2.05918367,  2.37142857,
        2.68367347,  2.99591837,  3.30816327,  3.62040816,  3.93265306,
        4.24489796,  4.55714286,  4.86938776,  5.18163265,  5.49387755,
        5.80612245,  6.11836735,  6.43061224,  6.74285714,  7.05510204,
        7.36734694,  7.67959184,  7.99183673,  8.30408163,  8.61632653,
        8.92857143,  9.24081633,  9.55306122,  9.86530612, 10.17755102,
       10.48979592, 10.80204082, 11.11428571, 11.42653061, 11.73877551,
       12.05102041, 12.36326531, 12.6755102 , 12.9877551 , 13.3       ]

y1 = [-0.21425007, -0.16045716, -0.10789988, -0.05657822, -0.00649218,
        0.04235823,  0.08997303,  0.1363522 ,  0.18149575,  0.22540368,
        0.26807599,  0.30951268,  0.34971374,  0.38867919,  0.42640901,
        0.46290321,  0.49816179,  0.53218474,  0.56497208,  0.59652379,
        0.62683989,  0.65592036,  0.6837652 ,  0.71037443,  0.73574804,
        0.75988602,  0.78278838,  0.80445512,  0.82488624,  0.84408174,
        0.86204161,  0.87876586,  0.8942545 ,  0.90850751,  0.92152489,
        0.93330666,  0.94385281,  0.95316333,  0.96123823,  0.96807751,
        0.97368117,  0.97804921,  0.98118162,  0.98307842,  0.98373959,
        0.98316514,  0.98135507,  0.97830937,  0.97402806,  0.96851112]

t2 =  [930.        ,  930.70707071,  931.41414141,  932.12121212,
        932.82828283,  933.53535354,  934.24242424,  934.94949495,
        935.65656566,  936.36363636,  937.07070707,  937.77777778,
        938.48484848,  939.19191919,  939.8989899 ,  940.60606061,
        941.31313131,  942.02020202,  942.72727273,  943.43434343,
        944.14141414,  944.84848485,  945.55555556,  946.26262626,
        946.96969697,  947.67676768,  948.38383838,  949.09090909,
        949.7979798 ,  950.50505051,  951.21212121,  951.91919192,
        952.62626263,  953.33333333,  954.04040404,  954.74747475,
        955.45454545,  956.16161616,  956.86868687,  957.57575758,
        958.28282828,  958.98989899,  959.6969697 ,  960.4040404 ,
        961.11111111,  961.81818182,  962.52525253,  963.23232323,
        963.93939394,  964.64646465,  965.35353535,  966.06060606,
        966.76767677,  967.47474747,  968.18181818,  968.88888889,
        969.5959596 ,  970.3030303 ,  971.01010101,  971.71717172,
        972.42424242,  973.13131313,  973.83838384,  974.54545455,
        975.25252525,  975.95959596,  976.66666667,  977.37373737,
        978.08080808,  978.78787879,  979.49494949,  980.2020202 ,
        980.90909091,  981.61616162,  982.32323232,  983.03030303,
        983.73737374,  984.44444444,  985.15151515,  985.85858586,
        986.56565657,  987.27272727,  987.97979798,  988.68686869,
        989.39393939,  990.1010101 ,  990.80808081,  991.51515152,
        992.22222222,  992.92929293,  993.63636364,  994.34343434,
        995.05050505,  995.75757576,  996.46464646,  997.17171717,
        997.87878788,  998.58585859,  999.29292929, 1000.        ]

y2 = [-0.11235382, -0.01261221,  0.08019689,  0.16640183,  0.24632084,
        0.32026221,  0.3885244 ,  0.45139624,  0.50915704,  0.56207678,
        0.61041626,  0.65442723,  0.69435257,  0.73042644,  0.76287442,
        0.79191369,  0.81775315,  0.84059362,  0.86062795,  0.87804121,
        0.89301081,  0.90570669,  0.91629144,  0.9249205 ,  0.93174226,
        0.93689826,  0.94052332,  0.94274571,  0.94368728,  0.94346364,
        0.94218431,  0.93995286,  0.93686709,  0.93301915,  0.92849573,
        0.92337819,  0.91774273,  0.91166053,  0.90519793,  0.89841654,
        0.89137345,  0.88412133,  0.87670865,  0.86917975,  0.86157507,
        0.85393127,  0.84628139,  0.83865501,  0.83107838,  0.82357461,
        0.81616382,  0.80886326,  0.8016875 ,  0.79464857,  0.78775612,
        0.78101757,  0.77443827,  0.76802165,  0.76176937,  0.75568149,
        0.74975662,  0.74399206,  0.73838396,  0.73292749,  0.72761698,
        0.72244608,  0.71740792,  0.71249524,  0.70770059,  0.70301643,
        0.69843534,  0.69395011,  0.68955396,  0.68524067,  0.68100472,
        0.67684144,  0.67274721,  0.66871956,  0.66475737,  0.66086099,
        0.65703242,  0.65327544,  0.64959579,  0.6460013 ,  0.64250207,
        0.63911062,  0.63584201,  0.63271404,  0.62974738,  0.62696574,
        0.62439601,  0.62206842,  0.62001669,  0.6182782 ,  0.61689412,
        0.61590959,  0.61537386,  0.61534045,  0.61586731,  0.61701695]
```

And so the task is to match/fit the **curve2** from (t2,y2) to the **curve1** from (t1,y1)  by using chi square minimization that depends on 3 parameters which are: the **height** of the curve2 that would make it match curve1, the **shift** in t2 on the x axis that would get curve2 on top of curve1, and then the **stretch** of the curve2 itself  in t2 in order to fit it to curve1.

**OR PUT ANOTHER WAY**

I am trying to match curve2 from (t2,y2) to curve1 from (t1,t2) and then when they have been fitted together appropriately, I need to figure out:

1. how much I had to shift the curve2 "back in time" (knowing well t2 starts at 930 while t1 from say 0)
2. if the curve2 had to be stretched in height (by how much?)
3. the minor adjustment in t2 (called stretch) to make the start/rise of the curves align as much as possible

**What I have done:**

I understand the task to be somewhat related to curve_fitting but I don't seem to be getting it right since I couldn't come up with a good mathematical function of the curve2 that would be required for curve fitting.
How do you think I should go about achieving this?

Comment: The curves don't even look similar. What would be your criteria here to imply that one could be transformed into the other?

Comment: I feel the curve2 from 930 -960 looks somehow similar to the entire curve1 and that range of points in curve2 is what I am trying to find how best it could be transform into curve1 with certain parameters . I don't know if this answers your question

Comment: Mhm. Curve fitting is the process of modifying the parameters of a function so that the difference to the observations is minimized. No function, no curve fitting. What one could do is a linear transformation of the data points to see how the overlay of the two curves looks.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection one see that the curve 2 is mainly made of two parts (As shown on the next figure) :

For low values of t the function looks like an exponentiel function.

For high values of t the function looks like an logistic function.

[image]

Linearly combining both, a more general function is proposed :

[image]

They are three parameters a,b,c acting linearly and three parameters p,q,r acting non-libearly. A non-linear regression is necessary to compute them.

RMSE=0.017 which is not bad but not so good as expected. Probably one can expect to find more convenient function for better fit.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably libraries to implement the suggested linear transformation, alas I am not aware of them. So, if this is just one example, why not code it directly?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
   
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(8, 10)) 

axes[0].plot(t1, y1, "ro", label="data1")
axes[0].legend()
axes[1].plot(t2, y2, "bx", label="data2")
axes[1].legend()
axes[2].plot(t2, y2, "bx", label="data2")

#transformation of t using the start points and maximum values as anchors
t1_0, t2_0 = t1[0], t2[0]
t1_max = t1[y1.index(max(y1))]
t2_max = t2[y2.index(max(y2))]

m_t = (t1_max-t1_0)/(t2_max-t2_0)
n_t = t1_0 - m_t * t2_0

t_fit = [(i - n_t)/m_t for i in t1]

#corresponding transformation of y-values
y1_0, y2_0 = y1[0], y2[0]
y1_max = max(y1)
y2_max = max(y2)

m_y = (y1_max-y1_0)/(y2_max-y2_0)
n_y = y1_0 - m_y * y2_0

y_fit = [(i - n_y)/m_y for i in y1]

axes[2].plot(t_fit, y_fit, "ro", label="data1 adapted")
axes[2].legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Different curvature, that's for sure. How to quantify this difference in curvatures, is another topic.